# ¿ Como centrar todo el contenido del pop-up?

Tags: css, html5, responsive

Quiero crear un pop-up para dispositivos móviles, el cual se abre después de una segundos de entrar en la web.
Lo he creado en un Block UX de WordPress.

**EDITO LA PREGUNTA CON MÁS DETALLES**

Con la ayuda de @Cris223511.dev cambia la apariencia y ahora se ve mucho mejor.
Pero sigue teniendo el problema que cuanto más grande es el dispositivo, más aumenta el `padding` superior e inferior.
Y cuando añado un Gif en lugar de una imagen, aumenta más el `padding`.

¿ Como corregir estos errores ?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
      }, 2000);

      document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
      });
    });
```

```css
#popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

.popup-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: max-content;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 90%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.popup-text p{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: rgb(203, 100, 15);
}

.popup-text h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup-gif img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#close-btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #26c995;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <div class="popup-gif">
      <img src="galletas-al-horno.gif" alt="GIF animado">
    </div>

    <div class="popup-text">
      <h2>¡Bienvenidos de nuevo!</h2>
      <p> Por fin puede comprar desde la comodidad de su casa</p>

      <p> Podrás disfrutar de precios exclusivos que no encontrarás en ningún otro lugar. ¡Bienvenido a una nueva
        forma de comprar en linea!</p>
    </div>

    <button id="close-btn">Cerrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yo veo todo el contenido centrado... menos el `h2`... que bastaría con ponerle un `text-align: center`... https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/qBJpBdw

Comment: Disculpa la demora en responder @Cris223511.dev , Hice pruebas, pero en dispositivos móviles se sale el texto por los lados. He buscado la forma de añadir  media Query pero no encuentro el punto.

Comment: Actualicé el enlace, ¿Es eso lo que necesita?... Más luego explico los cambios que hice.

Comment: Gracias @Cris223511.dev  , ahora funciona mejor . Estoy tratando de corregir otro error que se genera al añadir un Gif, en lugar de una imagen, me crea mucho padding y tambien rompe el diseño. Pero con una imagen, queda perfecto. Voy a tratar de corregir el problema de padding y siéntete libre de añadir una respuesta

Comment: He descubierto, que a medida que hacemos el dispositivo más pequeño, aumenta el padding superior e inferior en la imagen, he cambiado el código de la pregunta añadiendo el tuyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `padding` en tu GIF o imagen ocurre porque la altura de `img` es fija, por lo que mientras vamos reduciendo o aumentando la pantalla, la altura se permanece, dejando un espacio y haciendo que los elementos de debajo se permanezcan en su lugar, y así el `popup-content` se aumenta en el lado superior e inferior.

Solamente quitemos el alto fijo que tiene la imagen:

```
.popup-gif img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  /* height: 300px; */
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  }, 2000);

  document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

.popup-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: max-content;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 90%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  clip-path: inset(0% 0% round 25px);
}

.popup-text p{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: rgb(203, 100, 15);
}

.popup-text h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup-gif img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#close-btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #26c995;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <div class="popup-gif">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" alt="GIF animado">
    </div>

    <div class="popup-text">
      <h2>¡Bienvenidos de nuevo!</h2>
      <p> Por fin puede comprar desde la comodidad de su casa</p>

      <p> Podrás disfrutar de precios exclusivos que no encontrarás en ningún otro lugar. ¡Bienvenido a una nueva
        forma de comprar en linea!</p>
    </div>

    <button id="close-btn">Cerrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es que en tu `CSS`, tienes el `display` del popup como `fixed` y con eso no se puede mover del casi todo... yo usaría `flex` y pondría todo centrado... sería algo como así.

```css
#popup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.popup-content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <div class="popup-gif">
        <img src="galletas-al-horno.gif" alt="GIF animado">
      </div>

      <div class="popup-text">
        <h2>¡Bienvenidos de nuevo!</h2>
        <p> Por fin puede comprar desde la comodidad de su casa</p>

        <p> Podrás disfrutar de precios exclusivos que no encontrarás en ningún otro lugar. ¡Bienvenido a una nueva
          forma de comprar en linea!</p>
      </div>

      <button id="close-btn">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```